# reset preferences file

Tags: error

When I run blender from the run/command box, in windows 10, the program launches and runs correctly however when I close and reopen the program the original bug is still there.

I am trying to reset the preferences file to clear a bad reference. How, where and what is the name of that file.

Comment: Did you try to reset the preferences in Blender? *Edit > Preferences* to open the preferences, then click on the button in the bottom left corner *Load Factory Preferences* and then *Save Preferences*.

Comment: Yah! It finally worked it was so easy yet no one suggested it.